# What's the differences between these two methods of dynamically expanding an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

These two methods are trying to dynamically expand an array when needed.

Method 1.

```
int size = 10;
int count = 0;
int number;
int* intlist = new int[size];
in >> number;

while (!in.fail())
{
    if (count == size)
    {
        size *= 2;
        int* temp = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = intlist[i];
        }
        delete[] intlist;
        intlist = temp;
    }

    intlist[count] = number;
    count++;
    in >> number;
}
```

Method 2

```
int size = 10;
int count = 0;
int number;
int* intlist = new int[size];

in >> number;
while(!cin.fail())
{
    if ( count == size )
    {
        int* temp = intlist;
        intlist = new int[size*2];

        for ( int i=0;i<size; i++)
            intlist[i] = temp[i];

        delete [] temp;
        size = size * 2;

        temp = NULL;
    }

    intlist[count] = number;
    count++;
    in >> number;
}
```

What happens to array temp after method 1 is done? Is it necessary to free the memory of `temp`?

I tried `delete[] temp;` and pointed it to `NULL` but it messed up my `intlist`.

Comment: Why not use vector which does this for you?

Comment: Thanks for the answers but they don't really answer my question :(

Comment: Use `std::vector`. That does this job better. End of story. (Once you're fluent using the standard library, then you can explore such memory management yourself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 1st example uses `temp` to hold the newly created array, while your 2nd code uses it to keep the reference to the original array.

> *"What happens to array temp after method 1 is done?"*

It's going to be referenced by `intlist` further.

In the 1st case you must not `delete [] temp;` because it would leave you without any valid allocation.

---

In the 2nd case the `intlist` pointer is moved to `temp`, then newly assigned with another allocation. `temp` is used to deep copy the contents, and is deleted when done.

---

Anyway you should note (as mentioned in comments), that beyond academical reasons for research and learning, rather **[`std::vector<int> intlist;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)** should be used to solve these kind of problems.

Comment: @Lockie Glad to help. See my notes about your `intlist` member, please.